# How to encrypt many files with AES-GCM, without running the key derivation function each time?

Tags: aes, key-derivation, file-encryption, aes-gcm

Linked question: [AES encrypting multiple files](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5564/aes-encrypting-multiple-files)

---

With a `password`, I have 100k files to encrypt. (Maybe 100k files today; or maybe 50k today, 10k tomorrow, and 40k files the next week).

- Up to now, I did this (pseudo-code):

  ```
  for each file:
      plaintext = file.read()
      nonce = getrandom(bytes=16)
      key = KDF_PBKDF2(password, salt=nonce, count=1000000)  # very slow for each file!
      ciphertext, tag = AES_GCM_cipher(key, nonce=nonce).encrypt(plaintext)
      write to disk:   nonce | ciphertext | tag
  ```

  and to decrypt the encrypted file

  ```
  nonce, ciphertext, tag = file.read()
  key = KDF_PBKDF2(password, salt=nonce, count=1000000)    # very slow for each file!
  plaintext = AES_GCM_cipher(key, nonce=nonce).decrypt(ciphertext)
  ```

  Obviously, this is not optimal, since I run the KDF function for each file, and this is slow!
- I thought about this solution:

  ```
  # do this ONLY ONCE for each encryption session:
  salt = getrandom(bytes=16)
  key = KDF_PBKDF2(password, salt=salt, count=1000000)   # run only once

  for each file:
      plaintext = file.read()
      nonce = getrandom(bytes=16)
      ciphertext, tag = AES_GCM_cipher(key, nonce=nonce).encrypt(plaintext)
      write to disk:   salt | nonce | ciphertext | tag
  ```

  but this has the drawback of having to prepend 16 more bytes (`salt`) at the beginning of each encrypted file. Is it a common practice?

  And above all it has the following drawback when decrypting:

  ```
  for each encrypted file:
      salt, nonce, ciphertext, tag = file.read()           # since salt may be different for each file
                                                           # we have to run:
      key = KDF_PBKDF2(password, salt=salt, count=1000000) # very slow for each file!
      ...
  ```

  Since `salt` is on the beginning of each encrypted file, this means we have to run the KDF function ... for each encrypted file that we want to decrypt! This will be very slow.

  We could put them in cache `cache[salt] = key`, such that if we find the same `salt` again, we already have the `key`, but I'm not sure if this is an elegant solution.

**Question: which scheme to use to encrypt 100k files (in one pass, or in multiple sessions) with a password with AES-GCM?**

Comment: Generate a uniform random key ( depend on your need) use AES-GCM with a single key and generate the nonce sequentially. So you can encrypt up to  $2^{92}$ messages.

Comment: @kelalaka I need to use a `password` and derive a key from this password. Can you give more details about your solution?

Comment: @kelalaka $2^{96}$ maybe? In that case you should also indicate that a 12 byte nonce needs to be used.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes but this doesn't address the fact we have to derive the key from the `password`. And do we have to store the `salt` used for KDF in each encrypted file? This `salt` is indeed mandatory if we want to be able to decrypt them: without `salt` we can't decrypt.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes or can we just say: we fix `salt` once for all when we start the encryption job, in a `.encryptionsalt` metadata file. Then all subsequent files (today's 50k files, next week's 40k files, or even next year's 1 million files) will use **the same salt** for KDF, and only different `nonce` ?

Comment: @Basj why do you consider PBKDF2 is slow? We already need it to be slow around 1 second per call. If the files needed to be encrypted back to back then you may keep the key on the memory.

Comment: I'd use the same salt and include a key check value for the resulting key. You can use the key check value to test if the same password was used. Then use an additional 32 byte random value included with the file to calculate a new key for each file. For both the calculation of the key check value and data key derivation you can use a KDF. I don't like to rely on data limits for GCM and I'd use AES-256 for the lot.

Comment: Could you post more details @MaartenBodewes maybe in an answer? I'm not sure to understand here *"32 byte random value included with the file to calculate a new key for each file"*. This would require a 1-second KDF call for each file to decrypt? (too slow)

Answer (score 1):

One serious about password-based cryptography must not walk away from `KDF_PBKDF2`, but **run** to [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) (or [scrypt](https://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) if it's more readily available)! Bitcoin mining has (in 2020) shown that dedicated ASICs performing SHA-256 at high rate (220 TH/s) and efficiency (15 pJ/H) can become commercially available for few thousand US dollars. This makes it untenable to rely on PBKDF2-HMAC run on standard hardware for stretching of user-chosen passwords in high-security applications.

The method proposed has one characteristic: `salt` is common to several files if, and for wide random `salt` only if, they have been encrypted together. This is both a possibly unwanted information leak, and a way to solve the drawback mentioned: the password-stretching code used in decryption can maintain a RAM cache of (`salt`, `key`) pairs.

I'd consider replacing AES-GCM with [AES-GCM-SIV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8452), for peace of mind in case of stuttering of the RNG, but keeping in mind that two passes are needed over the data.

As much as I advocate trimming the last byte when it counts (e.g. when the data lies on a [barcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode) or goes thru a slow or/and battery-depleting communication medium), I won't recommend saving on `salt` and `nonce` size in file encryption like we're in the 1980s.